# how to brew install php56 via homebrew

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apache2

I'm trying to install php56 via homebrew , but it through this error message , how

> Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:
>
> 1. Perl is not installed
> 2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
> 3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)
>
> The output of /usr/sbin/apxs follows:
>   ./configure: line 8417: /usr/sbin/apxs: No such file or directory
>   configure: error: Aborting
>
> READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
>   If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
>   https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-php/issues

anybody know how to fix that ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install perl apache2`

Comment: I have a strange situation . After closing command line brew command doesn't work ? why ? It through this ** No command 'brew' found, did **you mean:
 Command 'qbrew' from package 'qbrew' (universe)
 Command 'brec' from package 'bplay' (universe)** error again  :(

Comment: no , not yet . For that I have to run like ** brew install php56 ** but after closing command line it doesn't work !

Comment: Let me check the error!

Comment: ok bro , no problem

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: Couldn't find why it shows that error on close. Not happening here. Still trying